# ASP.NET Core 3.x - Access IoC Container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

In ASP.NET Core 3.x, the usage of IoC containers like Autofac changed. Instead of returning some adapter instance in `ConfigureServices`, we have to use the new `ConfigureContainer` method.

My question is: how can I access the Autofac IContainer instance in the `Configure` method? I tried to call `containerBuilder.Build` within `ConfigureContainer`, to get a reference to the container instance, but then I get an exception that the container can only built once.

I am well aware that in normal use cases, there should be no need to pass around the container (Service Locator anti pattern etc.....). However, in this special case, we are using a middleware that resolves Command and Event handler types and it is based on Autofac. It needs the container instance.

Any chance to reference the `IContainer` instance once it has been built by the framework?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a hold of an `IContainer` instance you can follow the solution from the autofac documentation ([link](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#startup-class)):

> ```
> // Configure is where you add middleware. This is called after
> // ConfigureContainer. You can use IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices   
> // here if you need to resolve things from the container.   
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>                       ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)   
> {
>     // If, for some reason, you need a reference to the built container, you
>     // can use the convenience extension method GetAutofacRoot.
>     this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();
>
>     loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
>     loggerFactory.AddDebug();
>     app.UseMvc();   
> }
> ```

The `GetAutofacRoot();` in an extension method in `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

So in order to hold a reference on a casted `IContainer` you can write:

```
IContainer container = (IContainer)app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();
```

This cast is valid because `IContainer : ILifetimeScope`

Comment: @Shahad Shokrani , this doesnt seem to work as I get  an error Unable to cast object of type 'Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope' to type 'Autofac.IContainer'.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have dependency on the container you should add a dependency on `ILifetimeScope` and then resolve from this scope.

```
public class FooMiddleware
{
    public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;


    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        scope.Resolve<Foo>(); 
        await this._next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but does not help me, ILifetimeScope is provided by ASP.NET Core, but when I want to use it, it is already disposed. And IContainer cannot be injected.

Comment: could you share the code ? are you injecting the `ILifetimeScope` in the `InvokeAsync` method ?